Best way to make an animated line plot in streamlit?
I'm new to Streamlit and am trying to create an animated line plot. However, my data is quite heavy: I have 40 data points on the x-axis, and at each time instance, I am plotting 50 lines (the animation goes forward in time).
The parameters of the figure are selected on the sidebar, and each time the user changes one of the values, the entire plot needs to be recalculated (the entire time series for all the lines).
I am wondering about the best practice for this. So far, I thought about creating a gif animation using matplotlib and displaying the gif each time a parameter is selected. However, I'm not sure if that's the best approach.
Any better suggestions?
Code example:
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import tempfile


Z = st.sidebar.slider("Number of Ensembles", min_value=10, max_value=50, value=20, step=10)


# Create sample data
N = 20  # Number of lines
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.array([np.sin(x + phase*Z) for phase in np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N)])

# Create the figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lines = [ax.plot(x, y_line)[0] for y_line in y]

def update(frame):
    for line, y_line in zip(lines, y):
        line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + frame/10 + y_line[0]))
    return lines

# Create the animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=100, blit=True)

# Save the animation to a temporary file
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix=".gif") as tmpfile:
    ani.save(tmpfile.name, writer='pillow')
    tmpfile_path = tmpfile.name

# Display the animation in Streamlit
st.title("Animated Line Plot")
st.image(tmpfile_path)



streamlit and matplotlib are no best buddies when it comes to large amounts of data. What I would suggest is using plotly as streamlit has built.in integration with plotly.
Here is an example of how it's done in Jupter Notebook:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from ipywidgets import interactive

def generate_plot(Z, frames):
    N = 50  
    x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 40)
    y = np.array([np.sin(x + phase * Z) for phase in np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N)])
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'x': np.tile(x, N * frames),
        'y': np.sin(np.tile(x, N * frames) + np.repeat(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, frames), N * 40)),
        'line_id': np.repeat(np.arange(N), 40 * frames),
        'frame_id': np.repeat(np.arange(frames), N * 40)
    })
    
    fig = px.line(df, x='x', y='y', animation_frame='frame_id', animation_group='line_id', 
                  line_group='line_id', color='line_id')

    fig.update_layout(
        title="Animated Line Plot",
        xaxis_title="X Axis",
        yaxis_title="Y Axis",
        showlegend=False
    )

    fig.show()

interactive_plot = interactive(generate_plot, Z=(10, 50, 10), frames=(10, 100, 10))
output = interactive_plot.children[-1]
output.layout.height = '600px'
interactive_plot

which will render the animation perfectly:

Here is the same thing if you are not using jupyter notebook:
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

Z = st.sidebar.slider("Number of Ensembles", min_value=10, max_value=50, value=20, step=10)
frames = st.sidebar.slider("Number of Frames", min_value=10, max_value=100, value=20, step=10)

N = 50  
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 40)
y = np.array([np.sin(x + phase*Z) for phase in np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N)])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.tile(x, N * frames),
    'y': np.sin(np.tile(x, N * frames) + np.repeat(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, frames), N * 40)),
    'line_id': np.repeat(np.arange(N), 40 * frames),
    'frame_id': np.repeat(np.arange(frames), N * 40)
})

fig = px.line(df, x='x', y='y', animation_frame='frame_id', animation_group='line_id', 
              line_group='line_id', color='line_id')

fig.update_layout(
    title="Animated Line Plot",
    xaxis_title="X Axis",
    yaxis_title="Y Axis",
    showlegend=False
)

st.plotly_chart(fig)


Other than adding plotly to the requirements.txt configuration file, I was able to run this Streamlit & code directly on py.cafe, see it running here.

Click here to get this code in an active notebook session served on a temporary remote system via the MyBinder service. When that comes up, you can run the code. I found it usually took a couple of runs of the code cell to get the plot and controller to show up consistently...

  because otherwise upon first run, the plot & controller would not show up, or would show up momentarily and then blinks away. Alternatively, when starting it and the plot & controller momentarily blink out, slide one of the ipywidgets sliders. Because of the widgets needing an active session, nothing shows up in the nbviewer rendering of the static notebook. If it was solely made with Plotly, likely the plot & controller would have shown up in the nbviewer rendering.
